# Int *t; and this t[*t] - Type definition

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm working on updating a code of a server project since days.
I found a line that I cannot understand (which was commented)

First, I get :

```
int *t;
```

Then I got this (commented):

```
t[*t];
```

What's the type of this "t[*t]"

Answer (score 2):

The type is an `int` lvalue. We have two parts:

```
*t             // this is an int
t[ some int ]  // this is standard array indexing
```

Or for a simple example:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int* t = array;
```

With that setup:

```
t[*t] == t[1] == 2
```

Or:

```
t[*t] = 7;

// now array[] holds {1, 7, 3, 4}
```

Comment: It's also completely unreadable. Just saying. (Not your code, `t[*t]`).

Comment: @keyser: If that's unreadable (`t[*t]`), wait until you get to the simplest templates, or just about anything else.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer ! but how do you get int& from int ? Because I though the type was Int ?

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't follow. I'm not new to C++ btw :p It's not indecipherable, just obfuscated in a stupid way.

Comment: @John The type *is* `int`. My initial answer was incorrect.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Given the declaration, `t[42]` is an lvalue of type `int`; it is not of type `int&`.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's right. I was trying to explain the original version of this answer and messed up the terminology.

Answer (score 1):

The type is `int`

`*t` is equivalent to `t[0]` as such your expression is equivalent to the follow:

`t[*t] == t[t[0]] == t[offset]` (if you consider `offset = t[0]`)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes code is estimated by the number of typed symbols. So I would write a more confusing code but with more characters like:)

```
( t + *t )[*t];
```

Relative to your example

`*t` is some integer stored in `t` that is `*t`is equivalent to `t[0]`. Thus in expression `t[*t]` there is used the pointer arithmetic

```
t + *t
```

or

```
t + t[0]
```

that gives some new pointer that then is dereferenced

```
*( t + *t )
```

Answer (score 0):

By definition of the language, given that `t` is a pointer, the expression `t[*t]` is completely equivalent to the expression `*(t + *t)`.

To analyze the type of that expression, let's look at it step for step, from the inside out. I'll replace each expression whole type was identified with `«type»`.

Since `t` is of type `int*`, we have `*(«int*» + *«int*»)`.

Dereferencing an `int*` gives an lvalue of type `int`. Therefore we get `*(«int*» + «int»)`.

Now adding an integer to a pointer gives, again, a pointer of the same type, so the expression reduces to `*«int*»`.

But that is, again, just the dereferencing of a pointer to `int`, and therefore the final type of the expression is lvalue `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The `operator[]` of `int*` *always* returns an `int`.
Since `*t` simply returns the first element of `t`, `t[*t]` is the element of `t`pointed to by the first element of `t`.

Example:

```cpp
int *t;
t=new int[5];
for(int i=0;i<5;++i){
    t[i]=i+1;
}           // t now points to {1,2,3,4,5}
t[*t];      // <--- What does this evaluate to?
```

In this case `t[*t]` will be 2.
Because `*t` is 1, `t[1]` is the second element in the array, which is 2.